# Structuring a web page using CSS and html

Tags: css, web, html

I would like to construct the below web page while centering text and images in each section and keeping the web page responsive. Now, I tried everything from Flex boxes to Bootstrap's rows and columns, but it's either that my web page loses it's responsiveness or I am not able to center the content inside the sectors I am creating.

How would You recommend I go about the design shown in the image below while complying with these two conditions?

**Desired web page structure**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: try using CSS grid. thats the best

Comment: @Paulie_D My In short, my question is how to divide a responsive webpage while allowing features such as centring content. If you really think there are a lot of answers to this problem then please share one with me.

Comment: @Akshay L thank you for your answer, but I'm afraid that I have already tried that and I couldn't control the content's location and features inside each span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To design something like this you want to break it down into sections.

In this case we can have the *LEFT SIDE*, *CENTER CONTENT*, *RIGHT SIDE*.
I am breaking it down into columns because the laayout seems to be defined by the widths of these 3 sections.
Then once we have each. Just piece it together.

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
}

nav:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.side-body {
  padding: 5px;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #feeeee;
}

.header img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  width: 20%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.center-layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.layout {
 display: flex;
}

.left-layout {
  width: 200px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.right-layout {
  width: 150px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="left-layout">
    <div class="header">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
    </div>
    <div class="side-body">
      <h2>List</h2>
      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="center-layout">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <a>Home</a>
      <a>About</a>
      <a>Shop</a>
      <a>Contact</a>
      <a>Terms</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="body">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-layout">
    <div class="header">
      <h2>Info</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="side-body">
      <h2>List</h2>
      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Flexbox just makes everything easy.
Hope that helps.